# Python pandas: Keep selected column as Series instead of DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I select a single column from a `pandas DataFrame` using `df.loc[:,'A']`, `df['A']` or `df.A`, the resulting vector is a single-column `DataFrame` instead of a `Series`. I prefer to deal with `Series` as my remaining code uses `Series` specific methods.

```
#First, I assign a list of column names to the variable *col_names*
In [1]: col_names = ['TransID', 'BusinessName', 'Timestamp']

#Second, I read in an excel file and assign it to the *Account_Trans* variable 
In [2]: Account_Trans = pd.read_excel('Accounts.xlsx',header=None, 
                        skiprows=[0], index_col=False, names=[col_names])

#Lastly, I print the type of three different subset methods with the following output
In [3]: print(type(Account_Trans.iloc[:,3]))
Out [3]: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

In [4]: print(type(Account_Trans.loc[:,'Timestamp']))
Out [4]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

In [5]: print(type(Account_Trans['Timestamp']))
Out [5]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

My expectation is that `In [4]` and `In [5]` would yield an output class of `pandas.core.series.Series`. In the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/pandas.pdf) documentation, Section 5.3.1 (Getting) states the following:

> "Selecting a single column, which yields a Series, equivalent to
>   df.A:"
>
> [Section 5.3.1 Getting example of selecting a single dataframe column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePADu.png)

I recently updated to `pandas 0.23.4`. I've been working on and researching this problem for the last few days. I appreciate any help you all can offer.

Comment: what version of pandas and python are you using?

Comment: I think this might be a version problem? I'm using pandas 0.23.0 and I'm getting Series instead of DataFrame. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue

Comment: I also cannot replicate the issue, and I'm on pandas 0.23.4

Comment: I am using version 0.23.4. I'm not sure how I can help replicate the problem.

Comment: Do you have multiple columns named `Timestamp`? If I create a DataFrame containing two columns with the same name, I can replicate the issue. `.iloc` works fine as you'd expect as its using integer location for indexing.

Comment: @Ben I have one Timestamp column.

Comment: What happens when you print `Account_Trans .columns`?

Comment: Haven't tested - but you might be creating a list of list when you're doing `names = [col_names]` which makes it equal to `[['TransID', 'BusinessName', 'Timestamp']]`; try with `names = col_names`

Comment: @sundance Something unexpected happens when I print `Account_Trans.columns`.  Instead of a list of columns, I get a MultiIndex:  `MultiIndex(levels=[['TransID', 'BusinessName', 'Timestamp']]`.  I think this is my problem.  I am inadvertently creating a list of list when I do `names=[col_names]`.

Comment: @AsishM. You are correct.  When I remove the `[ ]` from `[col_names]` so that it reads `names = col_names` instead of `names = [col_names]`, my problem is resolved and `Account_Trans['Timestamp']` is of class Series versus class DataFrame.  Thank you!